# "Stand in Line" exercise on Freecodecamp

Tags: javascript

I don't understand a part of a JavaScript exercise on FreeCodeCamp.

This is the subject:

In Computer Science a queue is an abstract Data Structure where items are kept in order. New items can be added at the back of the queue and old items are taken off from the front of the queue.

- Write a function nextInLine which takes an array (arr) and a number (item) as arguments.
- Add the number to the end of the array, then remove the first element of the array.
- The nextInLine function should then return the element that was removed.

Here is the solution:

```html
function nextInLine(arr, item) {
  arr.push(item);
  var removed = arr.shift();
  return removed; 
}
```

This is probably very basic but I don't understand the "is stored in removed" on 4<sup>th</sup> line of the following example run.

Example Run:

- Test nextInLine([2,1]); runs.
- The nextInLine function is called. arr becomes [2]. item becomes 1.
- arr.push(item); Pushes 1 to [2]. So arr is now [2,1].
- var removed = arr.shift(); removes the first element. So arr is now [1]. 2 has been removed and **is stored in removed**.
- return removed; 2 is returned.

From my perspective, if 2 had been removed, what's left is 1 and 1 should be store in the variance because when we remove something we except and consider only the remainder which is 1.

However I clearly understand that the removed number is 2, so it feels like a step is missing or is wrong. Is my logic strange?

Comment: Did you mean `nextInLine([2],1)` instead of `nextInLine([2,1])`?

Comment: Welcome to SO! "From my perspective, if 2 had been removed, what's left is 1 and 1 should be store in the variance because when we remove something we except and consider only the remainder which is 1." -- I'm not really sure what this means. What does variance have to do with this? Can you clarify? Thanks.

Comment: @Bergi, this was the correction so there might be a mistake. From the answer of baao, it seems very likely.

You can see here:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/freecodecamp-challenge-guide-stand-in-line/18307

Comment: @ggorlen actually, I forgot that when .shift() is use, it returns the value. In the forum of freeCodeCamp someone said that "You don’t actually need the variable removed. The element removed can be returned directly using return arr.shift();." Thank you for the welcomed, I actually begin my post with "Hello" but it doesn't appear for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Example Run:

- Test nextInLine([2,1]); runs.

> You are passing only `arr` to your function. `item` is undefined

- The nextInLine function is called. arr becomes [2]. item becomes 1.

> No, it doesn't. `arr` is still [2, 1], `item` is still undefined.

- arr.push(item); Pushes 1 to [2]. So arr is now [2,1].

> Again, no. `arr.push(item)` pushes `undefined` to the array, so it is now `[2,1,undefined]`

- var removed = arr.shift(); removes the first element. So arr is now [1]. 2 has been removed and is stored in removed.

> Except from the array is now [1, undefined], that's correct.

- return removed; 2 is returned.

> Correct. `shift` removes and returns the first element of an array.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the error! I understand the example run better.

Answer (score 0):

Array.shift() removes the first item in an array, and **returns that item**.

For example, you have an array: const yourArr = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

`yourArr.shift()` removes "a" and returns it. Now yourArr = ["b","c","d"]

```js
const yourArr = ["a","b","c","d"]

console.log(yourArr.shift())

console.log(yourArr)
```

Comment: Thank you, nice simple explanation. I actually forget that it returns it...

Answer (score 0):

```js
function nextInLine(arr, item){
  // Only change code below this line
  arr.push(item);
  return arr.shift();
  
  // Only change code above this line
}

// Setup
const testArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

// Display code
console.log("Before: " + JSON.stringify(testArr));
console.log(nextInLine(testArr, 6));
console.log("After: " + JSON.stringify(testArr));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).